# Need to Combine value sets from two maps to create a third Map

Tags: map, community, collaborationgroup

I'm needing to associate new SF Community Users to the proper Unlisted Chatter Group within their Community via trigger/triggerhandler.  Hard Part is ChatterCollaborationGroup has no reference to Account, so I've created a workflow to create the groups via standard interface so that we have a set of records containing proper associations between group name and AccountId.

I've gotten as far in coding as having a map with Group Names associated to the proper Account ids and a second map associating the Group Names to group Ids. Names are set as keys because Id values are what I need to retrieve and parse.  It looks something like this in psuedo code for clarity

```
GName2AccountIdMap   =  <ChatterGroupName , AccountId>
ChatterGroupIDMap    =  <ChatterGroupName , ChatterGroupId>
```

I need to iterate through these Matching on ChatterGroupName to create a 3rd Map resulting with:

```
Account2GroupIdMap  <AccountId , ChatterGroupId>
```

final statement in adding a user to a group to create a new CollaborationGroupMember is within a for loop using "member" as follows.

```
member.CollaborationGroupId = Account2GroupIdMap.get(user.AccountId);
```

I just need help iterating over the first two maps to create the third.
It's a complicated use case, but really just a matter of knowing the right syntax to aggregate value sets for two maps into a third using AccountID as the KeySet and ChatterGroupID as the value set. Likely child's play for someone with more experience than I have.  All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right:

```
for (String name : ChatterGroupIDMap.keySet()) {
 if (GName2AccountIdMap.containsKey(name)) {
   // do stuff with third map
   Account2GroupIdMap.put(GName2AccountIdMap.get(name), ChatterGroupIDMap.get(name));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi something like this might work:

```
  //iterate over the keys of ChatterGroupIDMap
for (String name : ChatterGroupIDMap.keySet()) {
//check if GName2AccountIdMap contains key
 if (GName2AccountIdMap.containsKey(name)) {
   //add values to third map
   Account2GroupIdMap.put(GName2AccountIdMap.get(name), ChatterGroupIDMap.get(name));
 }
   }
```